# historic construction method resources

Tags: mechanical-engineering

### Could anybody provide a resource for finding or researching historic construction methods?

My current need is for a typical vaulted or dome ceiling construction methods circa 1992 in the US but I think it would be a helpful resource to have for the community in general. It is easy to find modern typical methods but I am interested in how the methods and processes have changed over time.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This will benefit the community?

Comment: Now I'm feeling old. Historic as in pre-cell-phone.

Answer (score 1):

The restoration and maintenance of historic buildings is the subject of a post-graduate course for architects, engineers and construction managers.

[This link](http://nps.gov/tps/standards/rehabilitation/rehab/masonry01.htm) covers some aspects of small, historic building maintenance.

The left panel has a chapter reference.